# Change Favicon SharePoint Online - Not working in IE

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page

I have made a change to the master page for my SharePoint site.

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/SiteAssets/pioneerfavicon.ico" />
```

This works as expected in Google Chrome, but it will not work in IE 10.  I have cleared my cache as well to verify that it was not the issue.  After clearing the cache, the original favicon is no longer displayed, and it is replaced with the IR logo.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this would work in Chrome, but not in IE?

Thanks!

---

I ended up doing the full path name of the site, which was unfortunate but now it works.